# Colocar una Imagen en PHP excel Con una Ruta externa

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Tengo el siguiente código para insertar una imagen en excel, el cual funciona correctamente:

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
                    $objDrawing->setName('imgNotice');
                    $objDrawing->setDescription('Noticia');
                    $img = '../images/new.jpg'; // Provide path to your logo file
                    $objDrawing->setPath($img);
                    $objDrawing->setOffsetX(28);    // setOffsetX works properly
                    $objDrawing->setOffsetY(300);  //setOffsetY has no effect
                    $objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
                    $objDrawing->setHeight(150); // logo height
                    $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($pos+1));
```

Sin embargo tengo una base de datos que tiene una tabla con unas imágenes cuyas rutas son de internet, por ejemplo `http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/beta/img/404.png`  pero para phpExcel no funciona, alguien sabe si existe alguna manera ? o necesariamente necesito la imagen en el proyecto?

Y sí, Ya intente :

```
$img = "http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/beta/img/404.png";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible.
La forma en la que puedes hacer es obtener el archivo con get_file_contents (o similar), guardarlo en tu local filesystem, tomar la imagen de ahí para tu excel y ya que esté en el excel y no la ocupas borrar la imagen de tu local filesystem.

Comment: vale gracias, ese  get_file_contents me permitría descargar la imagen temporalmente? gracias. investigaré más al respecto

Comment: No precisamente "temporalmente" esa te ayudará a conseguirla y ya está. Mientras exista la variable donde la guardas existirá la imagen. Investiga el método, ya lo entenderás. Pero la idea es esa. La obtienes la guardas en tu local o servidor, la obtienes de ahí para crear el excel y ya creado el excel borras la imagen.

Comment: holla, muchas gracias primero que todo me esta funcionando relativamente bien, por cada linea de mi while de registros de la base de datos traigo la ruta la descargo y la inserto, sin embargo como son varias imagenes siempre me inserta la ultima y eso que estoy reemplazando cada imagen en cada iteración del while, creo que el php excel guarda la rutaen temporal  y al final del todo imprime las imágenes? porque eso pareciera u quye si dibujara cada imagen al momento de que esta existe en el servidor no pasaría esto :/

Comment: Muchas gracias lo solucioné asi:
Descargo la imagen la guardo con un nombre incrementable imprimo todo y luego borro todas las imgs, gracias amigo.

Comment: Perdón, acabo de conectarme no había leído tu comentario anterior. Me da mucho gusto haberte podido ayudar. Si mi respuesta fue de ayuda y solucionó tu problema principal por favor selecciónala como la mejor respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Este es el código que yo uso. asegurate de que el `mdl` no tenga cierre de php

```
<?php 
session_start();
require_once '../librerias/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
include '../librerias/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
include '../model/mdl_usuario.php';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '../Classes/');
$cacheMethod = PHPExcel_CachedObjectStorageFactory:: cache_to_phpTemp;
$cacheSettings = array( 'memoryCacheSize'  => '15MB');
PHPExcel_Settings::setCacheStorageMethod($cacheMethod, $cacheSettings);

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
  $mdl_usuario = new Usuarios(); 
 $mdl_usuario->set("usu_id", $_SESSION['usu_id']);
 $datos=$mdl_usuario->listarById();
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("../documentos/fase1/chequeotsa.xlsx");

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$gdImage = imagecreatefromjpeg($datos[13]);
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing();
$objDrawing->setName('Sample image');$objDrawing->setDescription('Sample image');
$objDrawing->setImageResource($gdImage);
$objDrawing->setRenderingFunction(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::RENDERING_JPEG);
$objDrawing->setMimeType(PHPExcel_Worksheet_MemoryDrawing::MIMETYPE_DEFAULT);
$objDrawing->setHeight(0.44);
$objDrawing->setwidth(186);
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A1');
$objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());


header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Lista de Chequeo para TSA.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```